# How to install chrome-app typings in Typescript 2?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, npm, google-chrome-app, typescript-typings

I want to get rid of `typings` in our Typescript project.
With Typescript 2, I was able to remove almost every typings dependency, except the one for `chrome-app`:
https://github.com/uProxy/uproxy/compare/master...fortuna:master

This command:

```
npm install @types/chrome-app --save-dev
```

does not find the package, though it is available in DefinitelyTyped:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/types-2.0/chrome

What's wrong? How can I get the chrome-app definitions installed with npm rather than typings?

**Update (December 17, 2016):** There was a bug in the `@types/chrome-app` package that has since been fixed. The `npm` command above now works fine.

Comment: It's `npm install @types/chrome-apps` now. (`app` → `apps`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `typings` to install typings for TypeScript 2

```
typings install chrome --save-dev --source dt --global
```